# Create action omits user_id for nested attributes while saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have nested attributes of `shop` and `photo`. The `photo` should have the `user_id` in it, but when it is saved, everything is saved except that the `user_id` is omitted/ignored. But the `update` action works perfectly fine. What's wrong with my code?

```
# params[:shop]
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AtDD7EgDmX6uBIqdWwD3wwEGFg4tpCx28reWHHN1OmU=",
 "shop"=>{"name"=>"SNSD Hotel",
 "photos_attributes"=>[{"data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ffd0449eb58 @original_filename="hotel-spa.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"shop[photos_attributes][][data]\"; filename=\"hotel-spa.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/5_/5rfbktcs6398t6kb7d387dr80000gn/T/RackMultipart20130128-2801-107zje1>>,
 "user_id"=>1}]},
 "commit"=>"Save"}

# spots_controller.rb
 def create
   @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])

   photos = params[:shop][:photos_attributes]
   if !photos.blank?
     photos.each do |photo|
       photo.merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
     end
   end

   abort(params[:shop].inspect) # for discussion purpose

   if @shop.save
     redirect_to shop_path(@shop)
   else
     render :action => :new
   end
 end

# shops/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @shop, :url => { :action => action, :type => type }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <h3>Pictures</h3>
  <%= f.file_field :shop_photos_data, :multiple => true, :name => "shop[photos_attributes][][data]", :accept => "image/*" %><br>
<% end %>
```

**ADDED MODELS CODE**

```
# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true

  attr_accessible :data, :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :user_id
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the model code for shop and photo. You should have something like...

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
...

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
```